# Implementing error message when input is out of range in a list - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, indexoutofrangeexception

I am creating a code where I want to create an error message when the user picks an input number that is out of range in the list of objects. The code that I am working with is the following:

```
choose = int(input('Which one would you like to do a fundamental analysis on?:'))
share = (object_list[choose - 1])
print('\n-----Fundamental analysis for ' + share.company_name + '-----')
print('The company solidity is:')
print(share.solidity)
print('The company p/e value is:')
print(share.p_e)
print('The company p/s value is:')
print(share.p_s)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use `try`/`except IndexError:`

Comment: @coldspeed: good find. However, the original answers don't check negative indexes. try/except is inefficient in that particular case. Well, I'd answer the original question like this, but I answered that one instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could protect array access with a `try/except` statement:

```
choose = int(input('Which one would you like to do a fundamental analysis on?:'))
try:
    share = (object_list[choose - 1])

except IndexError:
    # do something
```

but that won't protect you against negative indexes (if `choose` is set to 0, then you'll access index `-1` which is valid in python. So I'd suggest a manual check instead (and I'd suggest to pre-decrement `choose` first to comply to 0-start arrays):

```
choose -= 1
if 0 < choose < len(object_list):
   # okay
   ...
else:
    raise IndexError("index out of range: {}".format(choose+1))
```

Comment: This looks promising! i copied it and placed around my code, but i still just gett an index error from the program.. I cant really see whats wrong! Edit: Got it to work now! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Add an `if` statement

```
if len(object_lis) < choose <= 0:
    print("Entered value is out of range")
```

or you can use `try...except`.

Comment: what if `choose` is 0 or negative?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre; Good catch.

Comment: the try/except is generally better, but manual check is safer in this case, because of negative indexes, yeah.